# Dynamically changing a property of a css class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build chrome like tabs which can dynamically assign a width to the tabs based on the number of tabs.
I have the following css class:

```
.myTab{
   width: 100px;
}
```

On every add new tab, or close an existing tab, I compute the width of each tab by dividing the total width of parent div by no of tabs.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="myTabList">
    <div class="myTab" *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index" >
        {{i + 1}}
    </div>

</div>
<button class="btn btn-default addTabButton" (click)="addMyTab()"></button>
```

Now, for the `myTab` css class, I want to change the width dynamically. 
One method is to iterate over my entire list of tabs and change the width.
But I was thinking if it is possible to just the change the `width` property of `myTab` class. If that is possible, no need to iterate over the entire tab list as the class is applied to all the tabs.
Is changing property of a css class even possible in css?

**Update**
I also need the tabs width not more than a `max-width` to ensure when there are few tabs, they don't occupy the entire width. This is why using `table` and `table-cell` doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

CSS-tables can do that.

```css
.mytab {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 25px;
  display: table-cell;
}

.myTabList {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em
}
```

```html
<div class="myTabList">
  <div class="mytab"></div>
  <div class="mytab"></div>
  <div class="mytab"></div>
  <div class="mytab"></div>
  <div class="mytab"></div>
</div>

<div class="myTabList">
  <div class="mytab"></div>
  <div class="mytab"></div>
  <div class="mytab"></div>
  <div class="mytab"></div>
</div>

<div class="myTabList">
  <div class="mytab"></div>
  <div class="mytab"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is adding a scrollbar when I have too many tabs.

Comment: Actually, it does work. Thanks. The only issue is, initially when there are few tabs it equally divides the width. So if there is only one tab, it occupies entire width. I tried adding a max-width, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Then you need to **update** your question to add these requirements.